# How to set multiple indentation widths in Geany?

Tags: geany

I use Geany mainly for Python, so I've set Indent Type to Spaces and Indent Width to 4. But when working with HTML, I'd like to use 2 spaces.

Is there any way to tell Geany to automatically switch to 2 spaces when working with HTML documents instead of being changing this manually all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set indention by filetype or by project. To configure it via filetype copy the filetypes.filetypename from data folder of your Geany installation into your ~/.config/geany/filedefs folder and change

```
[indentation]
width=4
type=1
```

to what you like. Please check [manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#indentation-section) for details.

To start configuration based on a project, start [here](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#project-management).

Comment: Perfect! On Windows, the `filedefs` folders is under `C:/Users/(User)/AppData/Roaming/geany`. Thanks.